# std::shared_ptr in a union

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, unions

I'm implementing a "variant" class which must have the smallest possible memory footprint and store some objects with a shared pointer mechanism.

For this, I would like to make a union within the class of all variable types. This includes some shared_ptr's.

The operator= and copy constructors must change the data type of the variant, hence switching to another member in the union. Upon switching to a shared_ptr, this one should be reset to null without deleting/deowning the pointer. Is there a way to do this?

Of course, there would be other ways to implement this but they are generally more complex, less safe or more memory consuming in my case. Any suggestion welcome though.

Thanks!

Comment: If "resetting to null" does not delete the owned object, then what you have isn't a shared pointer.

Comment: union isn't a great solution for any C++ code. you can also check/use `boost::variant`

Comment: Kerrek SB : not constructive comment... What about a special method different from reset() that would do just this?

Comment: @galinette Such a method exists.  It's called the destructor.  If you're going to replace a shared_ptr in the union with, say, a double, you must destruct the shared_ptr.

Comment: @KerrekSB If "resetting to null" deletes the owned object, regardless of the reference count, then what you have isn't a shared pointer.

Comment: Bryan Chen : tried with boost variant already. I'm trying to reduce the memory usage. By the way, most standard "variant" implementations use unions.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Right, I should have said "if it never deletes", or "if it doesn't implement the shared ownership semantics correctly". I was being brief, perhaps to a fault. Anyway, calling the destructor is just general "how to use unions", it doesn't really have anything to do with shared pointers...

Comment: @James Kanze : yes, I figured this, I'm actually looking for the opposite : replace a double by a shared_ptr. Your comment made me think that I'm looking for calling the constructor on the union shared_ptr. Could I do this with placement new?

Comment: @galinette As in my response: placement new whenever the union takes on a new type, and explicit delete whenever the union ceases to contain an old type.  (Obviously, you can cut corners when the destructors and constructors are trivial.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resetting to null isn't sufficient; the implementations of
`std::shared_ptr` I know also have a pointer to the reference
count, which must be deleted as well.

You need to keep track of what is currently in the union, and
use explicit calls to the destructor and placement new for
construction any time the type changes (and in the constructors
and the destructor).

Comment: By "resetting to null" I meant resetting the whole shared_ptr underlying mechanism to the valid state of a null pointer, but you're right.
I was looking for placement new, thanks.